# How do I reference the table being updated in the "set" portion of my update statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, alias

I'm using MySQL 5.5.37.  I want to update a table and I would like to use the value of the specific row I wish to update the in the query clause I use to get an update value.  So for instance, I alias my table like so

```
update session ts set
```

and so I would like to reference "ts.id" in the "set" portion of the statement, if that's possible.  I tried

```
update session ts set user_id = (select q.* from
  (select u.id FROM session t, training_session_org tso, organization o, user u
   where o.user_id = u.id and tso.organization_id = o.id
     and t.id = tso.training_session_id and t.id = ts.id) q);
```

But I'm getting a

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'ts.id' in 'where clause'
```

What's the proper way to reference my updated table in the query, if its possible?  Also, I want to do this in one SQL statement, not multiple ones.

Comment: Only alias the session table in the subquery, and do session.id = t.id.

Comment: No dice. GOt "ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'session.id' in 'where clause'" .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using a double subquery and `ts.id` goes out of the inner query scope, I suspect that you tried to use it for avoiding the error:

> You can't specify target table 'ts' for update in FROM clause

but the solution is just omitting the `session` table from the subquery as you don't need it:

```
update session set user_id = (select u.id
  from training_session_org tso 
  join organization o on o.id = tso.organization_id
  join user u on u.id = o.user_id
  where tso.training_session_id=session.id)
```

In fact, based on the joins you can even simplify the query further:

```
update session set user_id = (select o.user_id
  from training_session_org tso 
  join organization o on o.id = tso.organization_id
  where tso.training_session_id=session.id)
```